# Alinhamento com dois elementos no flexbox: Um centralizado e outro no final do flexcontainer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Estou tentando alinhar dois elementos na mesma linha: um centralizado e outro no final do flex container.

Eu consigo o resultado esperado com esse código:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex w-25"></div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center w-50 my-2">
        <h5>Cadastro</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end w-25 mt-2">
        <p class="mt-1">Inativo</p>
        <div>
            <kendo-switch formControlName="xxx"></kendo-switch>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Porém eu suponho que não é uma boa prática usar um `flex-container` vazio para alinhar o `h5`.

Existe alguma outra alternativa com melhor prática para realizar o alinhamento desses dois itens?

Eu tentei usar `w-75` na `div` do `h5` porém não tem o mesmo efeito, não fica totalmente centralizado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara o seu código está certo, não precisa se preocupar, e olha como a sua divizão está coerente, vc tem primeiro uma `div` com `25%` de largura `w-25`, depois uma de `50%`, `w-50`, e mais uma de `25` totalizando `100%`. Não tem mistério.

Se vc quiser, eu não acho justificável, vc pode colocar `margin-left:25%` na `div w-50` que vc vai ter o mesmo efeito. Essa é a forma que o Bootstrap 3 fazia...

[No Bootstrap 3 era assim](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-offsetting)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou se quiser usar uma classe padrão do Bootstrap 4 coloque `ml-auto` na `div w-50`, isso vai empurra-la para direita e como o Grid do BS4 é em `flex` tudo vai ficar ajustado! Veja no código

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- <div class="d-flex w-25"></div> -->
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center w-50 ml-auto my-2">
            <h5>Cadastro</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end w-25 mt-2">
            <p class="mt-1">Inativo</p>
            <div>
                <kendo-switch formControlName="xxx"></kendo-switch>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**OBS:** esse Grid que vc construiu usando `.row` e as classe de `width w-*` pode não ser totalmente responsivo, de preferencia para as `div col`

Comment: Deu certo, optei pela resolução com o ml-auto pois suponho que é mais didático pra outros programadores

Comment: @VeroneseComS sim é a técnica indicada! Só verifique a responsividade disso como comentei, ml = margin-left, e auto = a auto mesmo :D